# PHP Regex match four spaces but not five

Tags: php, regex

```
    This is a line indented with four spaces
        another one with eight spaces
    now the last with four
```

this is my string i want to preg_split on four spaces and not more, i am using,

```
preg_split('/^    /m', $str)
```

result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(41) "This is a line indented with four spaces
"
  [2]=>
  string(34) "    another one with eight spaces
"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "now the last with four"
}
```

I want the line with more than four spaces to be part of the first split,  I have difficulty in understanding the non capture or negative lookahead regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split on 4 spaces not on 5th you can use this negative lookahead:

```
$arr = preg_split('/^ {4}(?! )/m', $str);
```

where `(?! )` is negative lookahead that will fail matching 4 spaces at start if there is a 5th space next to it.

---

**EDIT:** To **avoid empty values in split array** use:

```
 $arr = preg_split('/^ {4}(?! )/m', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: btw any idea how can i avoid the empty value in start of the array?

Comment: check EDIT version to avoid empty values.